# So the code when you click a cdn link, how do I break it down to individual "commands"?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

And how do I use code from a cdn link in html and css?

Comment: For JS add the URL to the src attribute of the [`script`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element. For CSS use [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).

Comment: What do you mean with "click a CDN link"? CDNs usually provide JavaScript or CSS files. There is nothing you'd click on.

Answer (score 0):

For CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/cdn/style" />
```

For JavaScript:

```
<script src="path/to/js"></script>
```